# Python 3 - problem with converting string to bytes

Tags: python, xml, byte, crc, crc32

I'm learning Python 3 and I couldn't find any explanation for this.
The following function extracts and returns the content from the XML string:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import zlib

def parse_xml(session_id):
    root = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(session_id))
    session_xml = root.findall(
        './/{http://www.api-url.com/API_Service/}StartSessionResult')[0].text
    return session_xml
```

Example value of `session_id`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><StartSessionResponse xmlns="http://www.elektrotop3001.com/AAAA_Service/"><StartSessionResult>﻿&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;&lt;AUTHENTICATION&gt;&lt;SESSSION ID="3btqqSR5AUQSnDVBQ3dd5LAj54rekna3HPox7vYe" /&gt;&lt;/AUTHENTICATION&gt;</StartSessionResult></StartSessionResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Example result value of `session_xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><AUTHENTICATION><SESSSION ID="3btqqSR5AUQSnDVBQ3dd5LAj54rekna3HPox7vYe" /></AUTHENTICATION>
```

Later I'm converting `session_xml` string to bytes with `.encode('utf-8')`:

```
sess_short_xml = parse_xml(session_id)
sess_short_xml_bytes = sess_short_xml.encode('utf-8')
```

and the problem is that it adds `\xef\xbb\xbf` to the bytes object.
When I manually put the sample plain string to the `return` like `return 'abc'` the value of `sess_short_xml_bytes` is `b'abc'` and then it doesn't add `\xef\xbb\xbf`.
This is a problem because later I'm calculating CRC from `sess_short_xml_bytes` with `zlib.crc32` (which requires byte-like objects) and CRC result is invalid probably because of `\xef\xbb\xbf`.
Is there any way to extract and convert the XML content to bytes without modifying it? Or any way to properly calculate JAMCRC from this XML content?

Comment: Those bytes are the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character U+FEFF, ZERO-WIDTH NON-BREAKING SPACE, often used as a byte-order marker. Are you sure you don't have one of those in there? They can be awfully hard to see...

Comment: That was it! :-) Thank you very much. To solve this I did .replace(u'\ufeff', '') on sess_short_xml before converting it to bytes.